# How to insert JSON as string into another JSON

Tags: json, bash, yq

I am writing script (bash script for Azure pipeline) and I need to combine JSON from different variables. For example, I have:

```
TYPE='car'
COLOR='blue'
ADDITIONAL_PARAMS='{"something": "big", "etc":"small"}'
```

So, as you can see, I have several string variables and one which consist JSON.

I need to combine these variables with this format (and I cant :( ):

```
some_script --extr-vars --extra_vars '{"var_type": "'$TYPE'", "var_color": "'$COLOR'", "var_additional_data": "'$ADDITIONAL_PARAMS'"}'
```

But this combination is not working, I have a string something like:

```
some_script --extr-vars --extra_vars '{"var_type": "car", "var_color": "blue", "var_additional_data": " {"something": "big", "etc":"small"} "}'
```

which is not correct and valid JSON.

How I can combine existing JSON (already formatted with double quotes ") with other variables? I am using bash / console / yq utilite (to convert yaml to json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `jq` to generate the JSON. (You can probably do this in one step with `yq`, but I'm not as familiar with that tool.)

```
ev=$(jq --arg t "$TYPE" \ 
        --arg c "$COLOR" \
        --argjson ap "$ADDITIONAL_PARAMS" \
        -n '{var_type: $t, var_color: $c var_additional_data: $ap}')

some_script --extr-vars --extra_vars "$ev"
```

Comment: Cool, almost that I need. Could you help with another option? Is it possible build the same JSON, but have $ADDITIONAL_PARAMS as text (JSON text)? Example: 

`{"var_type": "car", "var_color": "blue", "var_additional_data": "{\"something\":\"big\",\"etc\": ...`

Comment: Use `--arg` instead of `--argjson` to do that.